# Writing a new motion planner

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing my own planner , called SplineBasedPlanner . It takes in a set of waypoints, and interpolates them with a special kind of spline (not the ones already implemented by ROS). The spline is designed so that a vehicle ,whose params are specified in config files, can traverse the spline smoothly. I want this to plug into move_base.

However, I am confused about what kind of interface (i.e. API) I should provide to do so. Should SplineBasedPlanner resemble base_local_planner's interface? Or should it be more like TrajectoryPlanner? Are there multiple choices?

I'll be glad to provide more specific information if needed.

Update 1: From responses below , I really want both  **both**  local and global versions for the SplineBasedPlanner.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29602/writing-a-new-motion-planner/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2012-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-13**:
Is this planner targeted towards generating trajectories from one waypoint to next waypoint?? As DimitriProsser explained below, it is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `base_global_planner` is responsible for drawing paths to the goal and around obstacles, while the `base_local_planner` is responsible for calculating trajectories and issuing `cmd_vel` messages in order to achieve the plan drawn by the `base_global_planner`.

Based on what you've written, it's not entirely clear what category your planner would fall into. I'm going to guess and say that you want to adhere to the `base_local_planner` interface (TrajectoryPlannerROS), but you'd know better than me. Which of these two do you think it fits better?

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2